# Images disappear when I try to upload my react project with github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I am trying to upload a React project to my Github repository.

When I use 'npm start' and view my project on a localhost everything is ok. I can see my images and the app works fine.
However, when I upload the project to Github and set up Github pages, the app still works fine but I cannot see my images.

My images are held in a folder inside the public folder. I have checked for case sensitivity but that's not the issue.

Can someone please advise what I can do so that I can see my images when I use Github Pages? Thank you!

Link to Github Pages: https://eulybin.github.io/memory-game-react-app/

Here is my code:

```
const cardImages = [
  { src: "/img/helmet-1.png", matched: false },
  { src: "/img/potion-1.png", matched: false },
  { src: "/img/ring-1.png", matched: false },
  { src: "/img/scroll-1.png", matched: false },
  { src: "/img/shield-1.png", matched: false },
  { src: "/img/sword-1.png", matched: false },
];
```

The above code is in App.js

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure why, but what worked for me similarly was to change the file name to include a `./` at the start

For example
`{ src: "/img/helmet-1.png", matched: false }` would become
`{ src: "./img/helmet-1.png", matched: false }`

and then upload that changed file on gh-pages for the purpose of displaying properly